# Odoo- Add domain filter on field after creating

Tags: python, attributes, odoo, field, odoo-10

I am new to odoo, I have two drop downs in my models, which are loaded from res.users . What i want to do is that when someone select **'Administrator'** or any other user in `first_approver` then that select user should be removed from `second_approver` drop down

```
class test(models.Model):
_name = 'test.test'

name = fields.Char()
first_approver = fields.Many2one('res.users')
second_approver = fields.Many2one('res.users')
```

I think it could be done by adding domain filter on second_approver but i don't know how to update field definition in onChange method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want domain then apply following

```
first_approver= fields.Many2one('res.users')
second_approve= fields.Many2one('res.users', domain="[('id', '!=', first_approver)]")
```

So the `first_approver` will not display in `second_approver` field.

<sup>Additional field options and other development help can be found in the [Odoo Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields).</sup>

Comment: That's Perfect ! Thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply same domain in xml also. if you add domain in .py(python) file same will be apply in database also.

```
<field name="first_approver"/>
<field name="second_approve domain="[('id', '!=', first_approver)]"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me thanx alot, been looking that for a while.